# ALSA: non-interleaved access not supported?

Tags: c, alsa

ALSA's [snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___h_w___params.html#ga4c8f1c632931923531ca68ee048a8de8) function fails when called with [SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_NONINTERLEAVED access type](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga661221ba5e8f1d6eaf4ab8e2da57cc1a), reporting that there was an invalid argument. The same code works fine with [SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED access](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga661221ba5e8f1d6eaf4ab8e2da57cc1a).

I tried to change the order of calls to snd_pcm_hw_params_* functions with no effect.

Next I thought that my hardware might not support non-interleaved playback, but according to [this post](http://mailman.alsa-project.org/pipermail/alsa-devel/2012-October/056321.html) ALSA subsystem will interleave non-interleaved data before sending it to the hardware if it does not support non-interleaved playback itself. Thus, non-interleaved access should always be available.

Why is it then, that non-interleaved access seems not be unsupported?

Following is the code that works fine for interleaved playback, but produces this problem for non-interleaved playback:

```
int err;
if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc(&hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ALSA: allocate hw_params error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    throw 5;
}
if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any(pb_dev, hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ALSA: hw_params_any error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    throw 5;
}
if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(pb_dev, hw_params, (pAudioCtx->sample_fmt < AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8P) ? SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED : SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_NONINTERLEAVED)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ALSA: set access type error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    throw 5;
}
if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(pb_dev, hw_params, pAudioCtx->channels)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ALSA: set channel count error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    throw 5;
}

snd_pcm_format_t sample_format;
switch (pAudioCtx->sample_fmt) {
    case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8: case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8P: sample_format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8; break;
    case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16: case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P: sample_format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16; break;
    case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32: case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32P: sample_format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S32; break;
    case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT: case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP: sample_format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_FLOAT; break;
    case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL: case AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBLP: sample_format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_FLOAT64; break;
    default: fprintf(stderr, "sampleformat %d is not supported\n", pAudioCtx->sample_fmt);
        throw 5;
}

if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(pb_dev, hw_params, sample_format)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ALSA: set sample format error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    throw 5;
}
if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(pb_dev, hw_params, (unsigned int*)&pAudioCtx->sample_rate, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ALSA: set sample rate error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    throw 5;
}

if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params(pb_dev, hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ALSA: set parameters error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    throw 5;
}
```

Executing this yields following output:

```
ALSA: set access type error: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hw_params_set_*` functions accept only those values that are supported by the device.

Most of the default devices (`plughw`, `default`, etc.) support automatic conversions, and thus accept all formats.
`hw` devices do not.